# SQL Join one-to-many tables, selecting only most recent entries

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is my first post - so I apologise if it's in the wrong seciton!

I'm joining two tables with a one-to-many relationship using their respective ID numbers: but I only want to return the most recent record for the joined table and I'm not entirely sure where to even start!

My original code for returning everything is shown below:

```
SELECT table_DATES.[date-ID], *
FROM table_CORE LEFT JOIN table_DATES ON [table_CORE].[core-ID] =     table_DATES.[date-ID]
WHERE table_CORE.[core-ID] Like '*'
ORDER BY [table_CORE].[core-ID], [table_DATES].[iteration];
```

This returns a group of records: showing every matching ID between table_CORE and table_DATES:

```
table_CORE date-ID iteration
1   1   1
1   1   2
1   1   3
2   2   1
2   2   2
3   3   1
4   4   1
```

But I need to return only the date with the maximum value in the "iteration" field as shown below

```
table_CORE date-ID iteration  Additional data
1   1   3    MoreInfo
2   2   2    MoreInfo
3   3   1    MoreInfo
4   4   1    MoreInfo
```

I really don't even know where to start - obviously it's going to be a JOIN query of *some* sort - but I'm not sure how to get the subquery to return only the highest iteration for each item in table 2's ID field?

Hope that makes sense - I'll reword if it comes to it!

--edit--
I'm wondering how to integrate that when I'm needing all the fields from table 1 (table_CORE in this case) and all the fields from table2 (table_DATES) joined as well?

Both tables have additional fields that will need to be merged.

I'm pretty sure I can just add the fields into the "SELECT" and "GROUP BY" clauses, but there are around 40 fields altogether (and typing all of them will be tedious!)

Comment: Thanks for the help everybody! I've had the prototype deadline rushed forward (by two months) - meaning I need to get the prototype of the database out before I leave for my holiday... which is tomorrow...

I'll be leaving the grouping of dates out until I get back from my holiday - but in the meantime, thanks everybody! I'll ressurect the thread when I get back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make sure that I have everything you’re asking for right, I am going to restate some of your question and then answer it.

Your source tables look like this:

**table_core:**

[image: table_core_output]

**table_dates:**

[image: table_dates_output]

And your outputs are like this:

**Current:**

[image: current_joined_output]

**Desired:**

[image: desired_output]

In order to make that happen all you need to do is use a subquery (or a [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)) as a “cross-reference” table. (I used temp tables to recreate your data example and `_` in place of the `-` in your column names).

```
--Loading the example data
create table #table_core
    (
        core_id int not null
    )

create table #table_dates
    (
        date_id int not null
        , iteration int not null
        , additional_data varchar(25) null
    )

insert into #table_core values (1), (2), (3), (4)

insert into #table_dates values (1,1, 'More Info 1'),(1,2, 'More Info 2'),(1,3, 'More Info 3'),(2,1, 'More Info 4'),(2,2, 'More Info 5'),(3,1, 'More Info 6'),(4,1, 'More Info 7')

--select query needed for desired output (using a CTE)
; with iter_max as 
    (
        select td.date_id
        , max(td.iteration) as iteration_max
        from #table_dates as td
        group by td.date_id
    )
select tc.*
, td.*
from #table_core as tc
left join iter_max as im on tc.core_id = im.date_id
inner join #table_dates as td on im.date_id = td.date_id
                             and im.iteration_max = td.iteration
```

Comment: Data stated is right, except the table_CORE has additional fields apart from the ID; though I'm pretty sure your code will work even in that case (I'll be confirming later, as I've been asked to rush out the prototype of the database before the end of tomorrow (it was supposed to be a two-month project...)

Comment: @CallumP.Robertson It should work no matter how many other fields are in/selected from either table. Good luck with the prototype!

Comment: There we go - managed to fix it with a slight variant of the above code! Thanks a bundle! Ps - Prototype went terribly: they decided it wasn't as urgent as they thought it was... Now that I'm back from holiday it's urgent again though!

Comment: @CallumP.Robertson Glad to hear it! Have fun with the prototype!

Answer (score 2):

Try using the MAX aggregate function like this with a GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT 
    [ID1],
    [ID2], 
    MAX([iteration])
FROM 
    table_CORE 
    LEFT JOIN table_DATES 
        ON [table_CORE].[core-ID] = table_DATES.[date-ID]
WHERE 
    table_CORE.[core-ID] Like '*' --LIKE '%something%' ??
GROUP BY
    [ID1],
    [ID2]
```

Your example field names don't match your sample query so I'm guessing a little bit.

Comment: probably worth using table aliases too, they're not explicit in the select or group by.

Comment: @PaulAndrew Lol - I forgot that WHERE clause was there - a relic from when it was compiled by the VBA. I'm struggling to make your method work when I'm including the other fields in both tables (about 40 of them!) - original question updated to reflect

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from 
(
SELECT table_DATES.[date-ID], * 
     , row_number() over (partition by table_CORE date-ID order by iteration desc) as rn
FROM table_CORE 
LEFT JOIN table_DATES 
       ON [table_CORE].[core-ID] =  table_DATES.[date-ID]
WHERE table_CORE.[core-ID] Like '*'
)  tt
where tt.rn = 1
ORDER BY [core-ID]
```